# Why isn't this IBInspectable property editable in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ibinspectable

I have an `@IBDesignable` class with the following property:

```
@IBInspectable var isSelected = false {
    didSet{
        self.delegate?.toggleViewToggled(selected: isSelected, object: self)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

But in Interface Builder, there's not the usual dropdown menu to let me edit the property. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The variable type needs to be explicit for `IBInspectable` properties. So, the code should read:

```
@IBInspectable var isSelected:Bool = false { 
    didSet{
        self.delegate?.toggleViewToggled(selected: isSelected, object: self)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```